# uniqueness of sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For the following equation,

$$ \sum_{x=b}^{N}(1-\alpha)^{x-1}\alpha^{N-x} \binom{N-1}{x-1} \left( (N+1) \alpha + x-1-N \right) = 0, $$

where $b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $b \leq N$. Simulation shows that this equation has a unique $\alpha^* \in [0, 1)$. $1$ is not included since $\alpha^* = 1$ always satisfies the equation.
Do you guys have any sense how to show it is the case?

Comment: What is $b$? Is $b \in \mathbb{N}$, $b \le N$ ?

Comment: @thinkingeye, exactly, now adding that to question as well.